# rooting my Videocon A55qHD

Tags: rooting

How can I root my [Videocon A55qHD](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/videocon-a55qhd-1064)? I mean the steps to be taken, and if required to install some app, and if required from where to be installed.

Comment: You can also use KINGO ROOT app

Answer (score 0):

If it's an OS <4.4, you can likely just sideload [towelroot](http://towelroot.com) on it and do it that way.